# use npm audit report in SonarQube

Tags: npm, sonarqube, audit, npm-audit

I'm working on web application.
I need to check security of dependencies.

I'm actually scanning my source code with OWASP dependency check but i think it's not the best tool to use on web app.
I think npm audit or yarn audit is better tool to check dependencies security of this king of application.

With OWASP, i use OWASP SonarQube Project to integrate result into sonarQube
Example of settings used :

```
sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DependencyCheckResults/dependency-check-report.xml
sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DependencyCheckResults/dependency-check-report.html
```

In the same way, is there a way to use the npm audit (or yarn audit) report into SonarQube?

At the moment i generate report in json format, using this command:

```
npm audit --json
```

I also know that it's possible to generate HTML report from npm audit with https://github.com/eventOneHQ/npm-audit-html

So, it's just missing a SonarQube plugin to import it or something like that, but i can't find it.

Comment: Where in the SonarQube application did you expect this data? Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @JeroenHeier: i updated my question, i hope description is enough to understand my problem ;)

Answer (score 6):

currently, this does not seem to be possible. however, [this npm rfc 0004](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/accepted/0004-npm-audit-xml-report.md) specifies a `npm audit --owasp` flag with solving this problem. this rfc was accepted, but is not yet implemented.

maybe it is worth a try to parse the output of `npm audit --json` with some sonarQube plugin, but I have no more knowledge about how to do this.

### Edit 2021-08-09

the npm rfc was [withdrawn](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/withdrawn/0004-npm-audit-xml-report.md):

> The npm cli team would be happy to land this change in case it comes from a community contribution, this withdrawn was based on the fact that this is not remotely closed to being in the roadmap of the current team.

Comment: Thanks @haja for the rfc link ;)
Wait and see

Comment: sadly, the rfc was withdrawn